# How to do a carriage return for a <th> tag in html

Tags: html

hello i have a table with `<th>` i want to do a carriage return when my titlle is long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either insert a `<br />` tag at the place you want the text to wrap or use the CSS style `white-space:normal` to allow the browser to split the text at a place it thinks best. Since this rarely works well, you should also give the column a specific width so the break appears in a nice place.

Comment: a) You should mention that in your question. b) What exactly isn't working?